# How to resolve this MongoError : command find requires authentication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I installed a local instance of mongodb with password connection using docker and linked it to my backend in node.js. Everything works fine on my laptop. The problem is when I put the mongo with docker and my backend on a vps I got a weird error from the backend when testing the endpoints : `MongoError: command find requires authentication`

I tried to investigate and at first I thought there were some problems with mongo config file so I ran this command : `db._adminCommand( {getCmdLineOpts: 1})` and I got this output :

```
{
    "argv" : [
        "mongod",
        "--auth",
        "--bind_ip_all"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "net" : {
            "bindIp" : "*"
        },
        "security" : {
            "authorization" : "enabled"
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

which shows that authorization is activated.

Also I got no erros while running my backend that would tell me that there were a connection error. On contrary while running this server :

```
@Configuration({
  ...config,
  acceptMimes: ["application/json"],
  httpPort: process.env.PORT || 8083,
  httpsPort: false, // CHANGE
  mongoose: [
    {
      id: "mydb",
      url: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb",
      connectionOptions: {
        user: process.env.USER_MONGO_MYDB,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD_MONGO_MYDB
      }
    }
  ],
  componentsScan: [
    `${rootDir}/protocols/*.ts` // scan protocols directory
  ],
  mount: {
    "/rest": [
      `${rootDir}/controllers/**/*.ts`
    ],
    "/": [IndexCtrl]
  },
  views: {
    root: `${rootDir}/../views`,
    viewEngine: "ejs"
  },
  exclude: [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
})
export class Server {
  @Inject()
  app: PlatformApplication;

  @Configuration()
  settings: Configuration;
}
```

I got a log that would tell me that connection was successful :

```
[2021-06-18T16:07:42.391] [INFO ] [TSED] - Connect to mongo database: mydb
(node:18398) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:18398) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

I have no idea where to investigate and how to solve the problem ? Anyone has any recommendation ?

I'll put here my dockerfile docker-compose and other config files I used for the mongo instance if that can be of any help :

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongodb:
        build: .
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}"
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
        volumes:
            - ./database:/data/db
            - ./log/:/var/log/mongodb/
            - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
COPY seed-data.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY .env /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf
```

mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# security settings including user password protection
security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

seed-data.js :

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "user",
      pwd: "userpassword",
      roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
    }
 )
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
        if [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" ] && [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            rootAuthDatabase='admin'

            "${mongo[@]}" "$rootAuthDatabase" <<-EOJS
                db.createUser({
                    user: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"),
                    pwd: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"),
                    roles: [ { role: 'root', db: $(_js_escape "$rootAuthDatabase") } ]
                })
            EOJS
        fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, really stupid mistake : I forgot to put back the .env file after I pulled the repo into the vps. The backend received undefined instead of `process.env.USER_MONGO_MYDB` and `process.env.PASSWORD_MONGO_MYDB` and was not throwing any mongo connection error !